# FormApp setPoints does not allow "0" as a value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I am writing an App Script using FormApp to reset the values of quiz items to 0. However when I call setPoints(0) it is throwing "Invalid data updating form."

I am trying to set the points of individual items of a form to 0 i.e. basically clear the points of an item. However, when I try to call item.setPoints(0) it is throwing the error of "Invalid data updating form."

Here's my small function that I've written, with dummy form URLs and IDs:

```
function removePoints() {
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1CXia_B4h7M2Dk1r8mhTLNyoTrz07dwdty5aiTh5v8QA/edit");
  var items = form.getItems();
  var item = form.getItemById(336898556);
  item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setPoints(0);
}
```

Expected results would be to have set 0 points on given item id. 
But instead, I am getting following error:

```
Invalid data updating form
```

Is there anything wrong that I am doing? Or is there any other way to reset a item's scores?

Thanks for help in advance. :)

Comment: Update: I've also opened an issue on [google tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122715934). Please start the issue if you are facing the same.